# how to show just Admin name from users table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relation

i have a user table :

[image: user table]

and i have a realtion between user and roles :

role Model :

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

user Model :

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

and i have view for show users like this :

```
<select class="col-12 border mt-2 pt-2" name="reciever">
        @foreach($users as $user)
                <option value="">{{ $user->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

and this is controller :

```
$users = User::all();
return view('Form1.add', compact('users'));
```

but in view, i want to show just user with role Admin, how can i do this ?

this is role table :

[image: role table]

and this is pivot table between user and role like this :

[image: pivot table between users and roles]

i just want to show user with Admin role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `whereHas()` method to query your `User` records against their assigned `Role` record(s) (via the `roles()` relationship):

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

```
$adminUsers = User::whereHas('roles', function ($subQuery) { 
  $subQuery->where('name', 'Admin');
}->get();
```

Alternatively, you can query the `Role` for it's `User` records (via the `users()` relationship):

```
$adminUsers = Role::where('name', 'Admin')->firstOrFail()->users;
```

Either approach will return you the `User` record(s) associated with your Admin `Role`